# Is it possible to disable SwiperJS on certain breakpoints?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx, swiper.js

As the title says, im wondering if it's possible to disable a Swiper when hitting a certain breakpoint within React?

```
<Swiper 
breakpoints={{ 640: { 
slidesPerView: 1 
}, strong text
768: { 
slidesPerView: 2 
}, 
1024: { 
slidesPerView: 3, enabled: false 
} 
}} >
```

After looking at the docs, I thought it would be possible to do something like above but this seems to work once and then doesn't re-enable?

is this something that is feasible? Sorry if I've overlooked something in the documentation or something, but any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Documentation says, _"Not all parameters can be changed in breakpoints, only those which do not require different layout and logic, like slidesPerView, slidesPerGroup, spaceBetween, grid.rows. Such parameters like loop and effect won't work"_ - my guess would be, `enabled` also falls into the latter category.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the reply! yeah, i saw that too and figured it would probably be the case. Wasn't sure if there was a workaround or something that someone knew

Comment: swiper.disable(), swiper.destroy() --> https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#method-swiper-disable